# Selection css em tabelas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou tentando aplicar a propriedade css de selection a uma tabela css, mas ela não está funcionando. Teria como fazer isso de outra forma. Segue abaixo o código.

```
<style>
  .hora::selection{
    background-color: #000;
  }
</style>
<table class="table table-hover">
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>06:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>06:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>06:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>06:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>07:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>07:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>07:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>07:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>08:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>08:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>08:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>08:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>09:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>09:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>09:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>09:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>10:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>10:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>10:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>10:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>11:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>11:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>11:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>11:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>12:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>12:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>12:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>12:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>13:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>13:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>13:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>13:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>14:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>14:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>14:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>14:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>15:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>15:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>15:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>15:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>16:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>16:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>16:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>16:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>17:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>17:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>17:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>17:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>18:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>18:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>18:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>19:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>19:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>19:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>19:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>20:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>20:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>20:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>20:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>21:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>21:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>21:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>22:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>22:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>22:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>22:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>23:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>23:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>23:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>23:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hora">
              <td>24:00</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Olá Yuri, podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"aplicar a propriedade css de selection a uma tabela css"_?

Comment: O que seria esse selection? ao passar o mouse por cima  muda o estilo do elemento? Ou ao clicar muda ? Como assim?

Comment: Quando eu clicar com o botão esquerdo e arrastar ele vai selecionar o conteúdo e aplicar o css

Comment: o selection ativa quando vc seleciona algo com o mouse

Comment: `::selection {
    color: white; 
    background: red;
}`

Comment: é exatamente isso, mas ele n funcionou com as tr da tabela

Comment: eu preciso só nelas

Comment: Eu tentei fazer também da seguinte forma, o primeiro click equivale a hora inicial e  segundo equivale a hora final daí ele marca todo o conteúdo que está entre e hora inicial e a hora final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens que colocar o `::selection` no elemento que contém o texto, no caso você está atribuindo ele à `tr`, mas o texto está na `td`, então acredito que esse seletor soluciona o seu problema:

```
.hora td:first-child::selection {
      color: white;
      background: red;
}
```

```css
.hora {
  background-color: #000;
}

.hora td:first-child::selection {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>06:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>06:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>06:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>06:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>07:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>07:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>07:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>07:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>08:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>08:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>08:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>08:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>09:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>09:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>09:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>09:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>10:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>10:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>10:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>10:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>11:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>11:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>11:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>11:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>12:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>12:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>12:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>12:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>13:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>13:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>13:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>13:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>14:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>14:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>14:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>14:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>15:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>15:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>15:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>15:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>16:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>16:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>16:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>16:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>17:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>17:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>17:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>17:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>18:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>18:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>18:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>18:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>19:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>19:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>19:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>19:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>20:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>20:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>20:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>20:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>21:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>21:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>21:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>21:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>22:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>22:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>22:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>22:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>23:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>23:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>23:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>23:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hora">
    <td>24:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```